# How can I hit a local dev server from UI generated by apiary command line tool

Tags: apiblueprint, apiary

I am using `apiary preview --server` to watch a file while editing it and have a UI generated.

I would like to hit a local dev server in the "Try" section of the UI, but when I hit "Call Resource", a request is made to `POST https://jsapi.apiary.io/apis/null/http-transactions/`.

`HOST` is set to `http://localhost:3050` and I'm expecting it to hit that endpoint.

How can I change this?

`$ apiary version
0.5.2`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, all console calls are routed via `apiary.io` servers to work around CORS limitations.

If published, you can work around this limitation by exposing your local port using service such as [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).

There is a testing of a version of the console that would make calls to the API directly and would utilise browser plugin if needed to get around CORS limitations. You should be able to utilise them soon.

Comment: @balupton There is a beta some people are testing—you can try asking support to be included :)